# org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore stores shape files in the database but files stored in own tables

Tags: postgis, geotools

Using geotools to store shape files in a PostgreSQL database. Each shape file is being stored in it's own table in the database. Is there a way to store the files in a single table? Also, the tables created for each file have a different structure. Is there a way to check the shape files to know the difference in tables that will be created and group the files accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If GeoTools is storing your shapefiles in separate tables then it will be because you asked it to. When you create a `JDBCDataStore` on a PostGIS database you specify the database and schema, then you create `FeatureSource`s (and `FeatureStore`s if you want to write) using a `FeatureType` (confusingly often referred to as a schema) that specifies the table name and layout.

So I suspect that when you read in your shapefiles you use the `schema` of the shapefile to create the new database table so it shares the name and attributes of the shapefile.

You can of course open an existing table by using its name but then your features must match the table's. You can't modify the features' schema directly because they are immutable but there some helper methods in [the `DataUtilities` class](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/main/data.html) such as `DataUtilities.createSubType(SimpleFeatureType, String[])` that reduce the number of attributes in a `FeatureType` and `DataUtilities.reType(schema, feature)` which makes a new feature of the new type.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the information and help!