# org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore: add information that is stored with the shape file?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geotools

Is there a way to add metadata such as file name and file creation timestamp as separate table columns in the table when org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore stores a shape file in a PostgreSQL database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop thinking of your data as a *shapefile* and consider it as a collection of features.

So you problem becomes how do I add 2 fixed attributes to a stream of features as I read them from one data source to another data sink. As I [explained earlier](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/384251/79) you can't directly modify the structure of a feature as it is imutable, so you will need to create a new `SimpleFeatureType` based on your input type and add two new attributes to it ("file_name" & "creation_date") then you need to retype each of your features in turn and add it all the existing attributes and the two new ones, and then send them off to the data sink.

```
SimpleFeatureType schema = ds.getSchema();
// create new schema
SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
builder.setName(schema.getName());
builder.setSuperType((SimpleFeatureType) schema.getSuper());
builder.addAll(schema.getAttributeDescriptors());
// add new attribute(s)
builder.add("file_name", String.class);
builder.add("creation_date", Date.class);
// build new schema
SimpleFeatureType nSchema = builder.buildFeatureType();

List<SimpleFeature> features = new ArrayList<>();
try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr = ds.getFeatureSource().getFeatures().features()) {
  while (itr.hasNext()) {
    SimpleFeature f = itr.next();
    SimpleFeature f2 = DataUtilities.reType(nSchema, f);
    f2.setAttribute("file_name", myFileName);
    f2.setAttribute("creation_date", myCreationDate);
    
    features.add(f2);
  }
}

DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
SimpleFeatureSource source = dataStore.getFeatureSource("tablename");
if (source instanceof SimpleFeatureStore) {
  SimpleFeatureStore store = (SimpleFeatureStore) source;
  store.addFeatures(DataUtilities.collection(features));
} else {
  System.err.println("Unable to write to database");
}
```

This will be fine for reasonably sized shapefiles, but you might want to write the features to the database inside the loop directly after changing them to save storing the whole set in memory if you have very large datasets or a very small machine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try it out!

Comment: It worked! That's great! Thank you!