# org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore change column name from the_geom to shape?

Tags: postgis, shapefile, geotools

org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore stores the geometry for a shape file in a table column called the_geom. Is it possible to change the name of this column to something other than the_geom, perhaps shape for example?

Answer (score 1):

As I explained in answer to this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/384322/org-geotools-jdbc-jdbcdatastore-add-information-that-is-stored-with-the-shape-f) you can construct a new schema once you have read in the data and convert your features to this schema before you write them out to the database.

```
  GeometryDescriptor geom = schema.getGeometryDescriptor();

  List<AttributeDescriptor> attributes = schema.getAttributeDescriptors();
  GeometryType geomType = null;
  List<AttributeDescriptor> attribs = new ArrayList<>();
  for (AttributeDescriptor attrib : attributes) {
    AttributeType type = attrib.getType();
    if (type instanceof GeometryType) {
      geomType = (GeometryType) type;
    } else {
      attribs.add(attrib);
    }
  }

  GeometryTypeImpl gt = new GeometryTypeImpl(new NameImpl("shape"), geomType.getBinding(), outCRS,
      geomType.isIdentified(), geomType.isAbstract(), geomType.getRestrictions(), geomType.getSuper(),
      geomType.getDescription());

  GeometryDescriptor geomDesc = new GeometryDescriptorImpl(gt, new NameImpl("shape"), geom.getMinOccurs(),
      geom.getMaxOccurs(), geom.isNillable(), geom.getDefaultValue());

  attribs.add(0, geomDesc);

  SimpleFeatureType ret = new SimpleFeatureTypeImpl(schema.getName(), attribs, geomDesc, schema.isAbstract(),
      schema.getRestrictions(), schema.getSuper(), schema.getDescription());
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, I understand about creating a new schema. But your method here is different from the method you explained previously. How do I merge the two? And how do I save this ret SimpleTypeFeature?

Comment: also, how do you get the outCRS?

Comment: from your previous example, I am using store.addFeatures(DataUtilities.collection(features)); to add the shape file to the database. How would the above created ret SimpleFeatureType be added to this features? And added to database?

Comment: I tried casting ret as a SimpleFeature ad added it to features but I am getting a ClassCastException

Comment: `ret` is a schema so you need to convert your input features to this schema before creating a new output datastore with it and the new features.